# How should I pass data from react app.js to profile.js and set id in url?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Edited the post!!!

id coming trough login request, at the else branch at handleChangeId! it gets the correct id! i try to push at the top!

```
export function Login({handleChangeId}) {

const login = () => {

//node port egyezés szükséges
Axios.post('http://localhost:3001/login', {

    LoginUsername: usernameLog,
    LoginPassword: passwordLog,
}).then((response) => { 

    if (response.data.message) {
        setLoginCorrect(response.data.message)
    }

    else {
        handleChangeId(response.data[0].id);
        navigate("/App");
    }
});
};
}
```

than at App.js i try to get the id from the login Route, and push trough profile Route

```
let id = null;

function changeID(newId) {
  id= newId;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route exact path="/" element={<Login handleChangeId={changeID} />}
      <Route exact path="/profile" element={<Profile id={id} />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
); />
```

at Profile.js, i also try to get the id this way, but the value=null every way that i tried! And this is what im looking for - how to read and set the id and get their personal datas, when the users hit profile on the menubar!

```
export function Profile({ id }) {

    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/profile?userId=${id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response) {

                    setCustomers(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    alert("Data currently unavailable!")
                }
            });
    }, []);
}
```

Comment: Where is `id` declared? Can you share complete code examples so we have full context for what the code is trying to do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Edited the post, need something else? node request also get the right id!

Comment: `id` should be part of the component state, so when it's updated it triggers a rerender. Also, why not declare a `path="/profile/:id"` and navigate to that path and use a `const { id } = useParams()` hook call? It would save needing to update *some* `id` state in a parent component and triggering a rerender.

Comment: If I change "let id = null" to "let id = 78"  (this is the id of this user profile what i'm working with) Everithing fine, i get the datas ect.! So i just have to know how to set "let id = null" to "let id = current user's id"! Becouse in changeID function i get the right id, but out of the function it's null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

> ```
> let id = null;
>
> function changeID(newId) {
>   id= newId;
> }
> ```

Doesn't work because `id` is declared each render cycle with a null value, and simply mutating it doesn't trigger a component rerender with the updated value to be passed to the `Profile` component.

## Solution

Make `id` part of the component state so updating it triggers a rerender with the updated value closed over in scope.

Example:

```
const [id, setId] = React.useState(null);

...

const changeID = (newId) => {
  setId(newId);
}

...

<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Login handleChangeId={changeID} />}
  <Route
    path="/profile"
    element={<Profile id={id} />} // <-- updated id state value passed here
  />
</Routes>
```